# From where view have to receive data in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

There is a little (or not) bit of misunderstanding for me. From where view have to receive data? Someone tells that from model , others insist on controler. Whats the best way?

Answer (score 0):

In an MVC system, the view gets its data only from the model. It is the controller that manipulates the model. It can be tricky to understand but try to imagine a sequence that goes C -> M -> V in terms of end user to computer and back to end user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the confusion more or less comes from the semantics of "receiving from". Simply, the controller does "what" should be done with data, and the model answers "how" data should be treated. There is no send/receive innate to this design, however it is common that the controller module which is responsible for the logic of the program also calls the view i.e. grabbing the actionable information from the model and passing it to the view module.

E.g. The model can be a set of tools for the controller to convert the data into information, then the controller passes it to the view. You can replace the model module with a dummy function about how to read from the database and make the controller which does all the manipulations with the data. Or with a sophisticated model, the controller can be simplified. Either way, the controller is the one which calls the view.

Here is an example, with two solutions:

data:

```
ids   timestamps     logs
1    1564829039    "x"
2    1564829639    "y"
```

view:

```
def view_log(log):
   return "the log is {0}".format(log)
```

**Solution 1**

model 1:

```
def all_logs():
   return read_logs()
```

controller 1:

```
def give_me_the_last_log():
   return view_log(get_row_by_id(argmax_id_time(all_logs())))
```

**Solution 2**

model 2:

```
def latest_log(data):
   return get_row_by_id(argmax_id_time(read_logs()))
```

controller 2:

```
def give_me_the_last_log():
   return view_log(latest_log())
```

Comment: It seems like i have to pass all data given from model thru controller?

Comment: Or i have to call model directly from view and controller just call particular view without any parameters?

Comment: Aha so if your model is responsible to interpret data, for example converting the timestamp to human readable time-dates, this is a different kind of model. If this model of data manipulation has nothing to do with the logic of the controller and it is only about readability and presentation maybe you should integrate it as part of the View module.